# Sum of multiple of two prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $a$ and $b$ be two prime numbers.
Which numbers are in this set?

$\{ax + by | x,y \in \Bbb {Z}\}$

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ _distinct_ prime numbers?

Comment: Yes they are. This question wasn't on a test or something. I just wanted to know what is the property of numbers in thr set

Comment: Notice if 1 is in the set so that ax+by=1, then for any integer, z, we have z=a (xz)+b (yz) is also in the set.   The question becomes... is 1 in the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \ne b$ then from [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), any number can be represented by $ax+by$. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}= \{ ax+by | x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

If $a=b$ then $\{ ax+by | x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}= \{ ax | x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Answer (score 1):

What is the $\gcd(a, b) $? What do you know of the Euclidean Algorithm to find the gcd between two numbers?

Remember that the Euclidean Algorithm, to find $\gcd(a, b) $, not only returns $d$, the greatest common divisor, but also an $x_0$ and a $y_0$ in $\Bbb {Z} $ such that

$$x_0a + y_0b = d $$