# Sums of multiples of the two most recent primes

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

For all integers n > 3 there exists two integers 'a' and 'b' such that: n = a(Biggest prime smaller than n) + b(Second biggest prime smaller than n)

Formal Logic Statement:

∀n ∈ {x ∈ ℤ : x > 3} ∃{a; b} ⊂ ℤ | n = a * ⊔P + b * ⊔S where P = {p ∈ ℤ+ : p is prime ∧ p < n} ∧ S = {x ∈ P : x < ⊔P}

Found lots of examples for the first 2000 'n' using brute force.
I came across a somewhat [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018093/sum-of-multiple-of-two-prime-numbers) about if the sum of two integer multiples of primes can equal any other integer, which could be proven using [Bézout's identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Any ideas?

Comment: This is just Bezout applied to the two largest primes $<n$.  Clearly these are relatively prime (as they are distinct primes).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @lulu so according to what I understand of Bezout's Identity that means that the best we can get is: a*(P1) + b*(P2) = 1. Did I understand that correctly? Considering that there are lots of examples for n<2000 I'm pretty sure I didn't quite understand how Bezout applies here. Mind explaining briefly?

Comment: If you can solve $an+bm=1$ then you can solve $An+Bm=k$ for any $k$.  Just let $A=k\times a, B=k\times b$ where $a,b$ solve $an+bm=1$.